# Uploading Google Spreadsheet to a Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I'd like to begin by stating that the end goal is to display our company directory (a list of our employees names/job title/extension#/office location/email), which is in a Google Sheet, on a page in one of our Google Sites.

I tried to use Google's embed function, and it works... but it is very clunky, does not have a "Sort" function, and it just looks weird.

I pulled a Google Apps Script from somewhere online like 3 months ago and it actually did pull in a way that made me happy:

[image: Link to Screenshot of the Current page]

(This is as it appears currently on the Google Sites page. So in this screenshot, the embedded Sheet is at the top. The Sheet when, imported via the script, is below. Yes, they are both on the same page. I'm in testing!)

This is the code I used (I THINK - I don't remember how I implemented it):

```js
function myFunction() {

}

function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if(ScriptProperties.getProperty("page url") == null){
   ss.addMenu("List page", [{name: "Create list", functionName: "create_list"},null,
                        {name: "Fetch list items", functionName: "fetch_items"}]);
  }
  else{
    ss.addMenu("List page", [{name: "Push Items", functionName: "push_items"}]);
  }
}

function create_list() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var parent_page = Browser.inputBox("URL of the parent page:");
  var title = Browser.inputBox("Choose a name for your list page:");
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var list = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(parent_page).createListPage(title, title.split(' ').join(''), '', data[0]);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("page url", list.getUrl());
  onOpen();
  push_items();
}

function push_items(){
  var done = false;
  while(!done){
    try{
      var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
      var list = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(ScriptProperties.getProperty("page url"));
      var list_items = list.getListItems();
      for(i in list_items){
        list_items[i].deleteListItem();
      }
      for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        var item = list.addListItem(data[i]);
      }
      done = true;
    }
    catch(e){
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(ScriptProperties.getProperty("page url"), "List page updated", 10);
}


function fetch_items(){
  var url = Browser.inputBox("URL of your list page:");
  var col_number = Browser.inputBox("Number of columns in the list:");
  var data = new Array();
  var list_items = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url).getListItems();
  for(i in list_items){
    var row = new Array();
    for(j = 0; j < col_number; j++){
      row.push(list_items[i].getValueByIndex(j));
    }
    data.push(row);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}


[I do not take credit for writing this!]
```

So I would like to ask (since this ceases to make much sense to me) is if this is viable code for a Google Apps Script, and if so, how do I implement it to output Sheet data similarly in the same type of format as in the screenshot?

Alternatively, is there a better way to display this Sheet data in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

A totally different alternative would be to use [Romain Vialard's "awesome tables" gadget](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/awesome-tables). It works... awesome, and it is really easy to use. Besides, it admits filters, ...